# Контейнеры в docker не видят друг друга

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Я есть папка folder1 - там лежит файл docker-compose.yml
Есть папка folder2 - там тоже файл docker-compose.yml

Поднимаем контейнеры командой :
docker-compose up -d, все в состоянии up
Только находятся в разлиновал подсетях

Container 1 из folder 1 - имеет ip:172.0.25.12
А 
Container 2 их folder 2 - имеет ip:172.0.26.12

Контейнеры друг друга по сети не видят, не пингуют (разные подсети)

Как сделать так, чтобы эти два контейнера были в одной подсети и видели друг друга ??

Comment: iptables на хосте посмотрите

Answer (score 1):

Подразумевается что вы не будете использовать docker-compose так. Один docker-compose (ну и те которые его возможно расширяют) файл в одной папке должен полностью описывать все взаимодействие сервисов внутри него.
Если у вас сервисы связаны, но docker-compose у каждого свой, то возможно что-то пошло не так, и стоит поднять docker-compose на уровень выше.

Но если того требует случай то можно и извернутся.

```
networks:
  outside:
    external: true
```

Вот так можно описать внешнюю по отношению к docker-compose сеть, она не будет создана автоматически, docker-compose попробует присоединиться к сети ***outside***, и выдаст ошибку если она не создана.
Создать ее можно используя стандартные средства docker, или присоединиться к той которую создает docker-compose из folder1.

Также, есть вариант (не лучший, не все зависит от ситуации) запустить их используя  сеть хоста:

```
network_mode: "host"
```

В таком случае все контейнеры будут запущены на интерфейсах хоста, и будут доступны даже через localhost, но возможны конфликты с портами.